# gpg: Bad session key в duplicity незвисимо от флагов

Tags: linux, unix, centos, gpg

Активно изучаю админское дело и инструменты. Сейчас изучаю duplicity который должен делать инкрементальные бекапы на s3. Проблема в том, что независимо от флага --no-encryption он все равно пытается зашифровать файл. мне интересно почему так? Как то так это выглядит:

```
duplicity --no-encryption  /home/  s3+http://my_bucket/files
Synchronizing remote metadata to local cache...
Copying duplicity-full-signatures.20170619T191202Z.sigtar.gpg to local cache.
GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: CAST5 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

вопрос 1: почему он пытается шифровать? 
вопрос 2: я сгенерировал ключи и указал пароль через --encrypt-key="YOUR-KEY" - не помогло. 
На просторах рекомендуют агента перезагрузить - не помогает.
Такое чувство что gpg не корректно установился

```
 gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.22
libgcrypt 1.5.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ?, ?, ELG, DSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Centos 7

Comment: программу gpg, конечно, можно использовать и для шифрования. но чаще её используют для подписи (и последующей проверки). судя по приведённой вами информации, gpg в данном случае используется именно с данной целью.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Да мне она собственно в данный момент совсем не нужна на тестах. я просто не знаю как ее НЕ использовать.

Comment: судя по беглому просмотру [man-страницы](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html) — никак. могу лишь предположить, что подписи (signatures) — возможно, необходимый компонент алгоритма работы программы duplicity.